# Replicate tables to different database name

Tags: mysql, replication

Our QA environment has all it's database names suffixed with "test".  For example dbname1 in production would have a counterpart dbname1test in QA.  (This is largely to help protect against prod/qa configs getting mixed up).

There are a handful of tables I would like to replicate the actual production tables into QA.  I'm not sure how I would go about telling it to say "replicate from dbname1 there to dbname1test there"

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, there is. Put this in your my.cnf file:

```
replicate-rewrite-db="dbname1->dbname1test"
```

See [Replica Server Options and Variables: replicate-rewrite-db](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-replica.html#option_mysqld_replicate-rewrite-db)

Comment: Thank you, and my apologies for missing this in the docs.